# How could compute the centralizers by GAP?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Let $G$ be a finite group. How could we obtain all conjugacy classes of element centralizers of $G$ by GAP?

(By the centralizer of an element $g$ in $G$,  I mean the subgroup $C_G(g):=\{x\in G | xg=gx \}$ of $G$ 
and by the conjugacy class of $C_G(g)$ I mean the set $\{x^{-1}C_G(g)x | x\in G\}$).

Thank you so much!

Comment: I assume you are aware of the naive way to do this and is looking for a more efficient one than just applying the obvious functions to all elements?

Comment: Dear Tobias Yes! I want to apply a more efficient and shorter way to obtain them. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compute `ConjugacyClasses` you get a list of classes, each having a `Representative` and a `Centralizer`, these centralizers are (with duplicates if two classes have the same centralizer, e.g. Galois-conjugate elements) the different possible centralizers in $G$:

```
List(ConjugacyClasses(G),Centralizer);
```

Comment: Dear ahulpke thank you for  your useful answer!

Comment: How could we compute the centralizer of a subgroup in the whole group in GAP?